# Twig—print to root block

Tags: twig

There is a Template called `index.html.twig` which defines these blocks:

```
{% block additional %}{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
  {{ macros.renderModule(modules) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Whereby `macros.renderModule` is a custom macro the recursively renders modules.

Each module template (`<type>.html.twig`) extends `base.html.twig` like so:

```
{% extends '::/modules/base.html.twig' %}
```

And from within the a `<type>.html.twig` I would like to print to the `additional` block, which is the »root«. If I move the block to `base..html.twig` it works, since each type directly extends »base«.

How can I print to a block defined in the root?

**UPDATE**

Due to the comments, here a little illustration:

```
1.:

+base.html.twig      //root
|
+--+index.html.twig //extends base.html.twig and
                    //defines a block »additional«
                    //starts the recursive call »macros.renderModule(…)«
                    //those calls use the templates shows below
2.:

+modules/base.html.twig      //base for each module
|
+--+modules/<type>.html.twig //extends modules/base.html.twig
                             //special template for each »type« of module
                             //**************
                             //PRINT TO block »additional«,
                             //defined in index.html.twig
                             //**************
```

The macro for the recursive call of those modules looks like that:

```
{% macro renderModule (modules) %}
  {% import _self as macros %}
  {% for module in modules %}
    {% include '::/modules/' ~ module.type ~ '.html.twig' with {module: module} %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: You mean alter the content of the file in which you render the macro? Can't be done by default in `twig`

Comment: Can you be more precise of what you exactly try to achieve? If you want to render a block from a template not being part of the current template's inheritance chain, you can pass that template to the `block()` function (see http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/functions/block.html). But I am honestly not sure if I really understood your question.